# General solution of 2nd order linear DE with constant coefficients approaches zero as $x$ tends to infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Question:
Show that the general solution of $$y''+py'+qy=0$$ approaches 0 as $x$ tends to infinity if and only if p and q are both positive.

**Attempt**:

First assume $p$ and $q$ are positive and we are trying to prove that the general solution tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity:

The auxiliary equation is given by: $$m^2+pm+q=0. \space\space\space (*)$$ And, has solutions: $$m_{1,2}=\frac{-p \pm \sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$$

Well, what I tried to do is dividing it into two cases, the first case is with two distinct real roots, and the other case will be complex roots, for the case of repeated root not sure how to start. So for the first case: if p and q are positive, then the factorization of $(*)$ will always be of the form: $$(m+\alpha)(m+\beta)=0$$ where $\alpha ,\beta >0$, and so $m_1,m_2 < 0$, thus, the general solution, which we know is given by: $$y=c_1e^{m_1x}+c_2e^{m_2x}$$ will certainly tend to zero then.
However, I am unable to prove this form of factorization is "always" true if $p$ and $q$ are positive.

For the cases of complex roots and repeated roots, I have tried similar attempts but reached nothing useful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $p^{2}> 2q$.

$-p\pm \sqrt {p^{2}-4q}<0$ since $\sqrt {p^{2}-4q} <p$. Thus, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are negative.

Case 2: $p^{2}< 2q$. Here, $m_1$ amd $m_2$ are complex numbers and the solutions are of the form $e^{-px/2}(A\cos x +B\sin x)$.

Case 3: $p^{2}=4q$. I will leave this case to you.

Comment: Why is $m=-\frac{p}{2}$ in the complex case?
The formula I have is this:
$$y=e^{ax}[Acos(bx)+Bsin(bx)]$$ where $m_{1,2}=a \pm ib$

Comment: $a=-\frac p 2$ in the complex case. @Nero

Comment: Ohh right sorry; I just realized that now!

Comment: Thanks @geetha290krm, I was able to complete the repeated root case, and using your help, completed the proof and understood it.

Comment: Ohh the $\ge$ considers it as well, I see now. That condensed the proof, and made it more elegent; thanks again.